# Populate pager correctly

Tags: android

In my app I have a pager as main view, I'm populating it inside onStart() but when i rotate the screen it crashes (because it can't find the views).

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    createPager();


} 

void createPager(){


    // Instantiate a ViewPager and a PagerAdapter.
    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);

}
```

Where should i populate my pager in order to make it repopulate every time i rotate my device?

EDIT2:

This is the code of my fragments

```
public class WakeyFragment extends Fragment {

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            ViewGroup wakeyView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.wakey, container, false);

            return wakeyView;
        }
        @Override
        public void onSaveInstanceState(final Bundle outState) {
            // super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        }
    }

    public class PremiumFragment extends Fragment {

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            ViewGroup premiumView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.premium_features, container, false);


            return premiumView;
        }


        @Override
        public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

            setViews();
            buttonSetup();
            autoWakeCheck();
            cpuWakeCheck();

            if (WakeService.isAwake) {
                glow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            else {
                glow.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }


        }
        @Override
        public void onSaveInstanceState(final Bundle outState) {
            // super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        }
    }
```

setViews() is where i find the views in my xml for all my views with findViewByID(), buttonSetup() is where i set all my buttons with onClickListeners, and where i prepare my views with setTypeface, setBackground() etc.
Now my crashing is occuring when buttonSetup() is called, as soon as i try to modify a view, (this happens only when i rotate the screen)

This is the new log I'm getting

```
01-10 15:06:25.714  16847-16847/com.doublep.wakey E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.doublep.wakey, PID: 16847
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.doublep.wakey/com.doublep.wakey.Bulb}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2215)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2265)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3758)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1212)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5081)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:781)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.doublep.wakey.Bulb.buttonSetup(Bulb.java:604)
            at com.doublep.wakey.Bulb$PremiumFragment.onViewCreated(Bulb.java:1417)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:941)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1086)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:1884)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:566)
            at com.doublep.wakey.Bulb.onStart(Bulb.java:1015)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1171)
            at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5241)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2178)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2265)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3758)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1212)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5081)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:781)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Line 1417 is buttonSetup(), and line 604 is the first line of the buttonSetup() method where i change the background of a view

Comment: Post the code of WakeyFragment, in particular the class definition and constructors

Comment: Post your buttonsSetup() method. You probably didn't initialize your view.

Comment: I'm initializing my views in setViews(), buttonSetup() has the onClickListeners, also it works fine if I don't rotate the screen.
The code works fine, i just have to figure out where to place those methods to make it work with the screen rotation

Comment: Ok, i found where the problem is, I have to run setViews() and buttonSetup() outside the fragment, but i have to run it after onViewCreated(), currently I'm using a delayed post from onResume(), but this isn't a nice solution, how can i trigger those methods after the view has been created? (when onViewCreated() is called)

Answer (score 0):

Check the [Activity lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) and you'll see that `onResume()` is the method of choice.

Also each Fragment needs to have a default public constructor with no parameters.

Comment: Then probably I'm doing something wrong elsewhere, I've tried with onResume() and it crashes

Answer (score 0):

Your fragments appear to be nested inner classes.
Add the `static` keyword between `public` and `class`.

Comment: But then I'd have to make all my methods and variables static, or should i call all my methods elsewhere?

Comment: No you wouldn't. You need to revisit your architecture -- sub-controllers (fragments) should not directly invoke methods on the parent controller, instead you should require it implements some kind of interface.
Take a look at http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, I'm using a local broadcastReceiver and I'm sending a message from onViewCreated(), then i run my methods from the broadcast receiver, I don't know if it's the ideal solution but it works for now